# VBA PowerPoint point command button to private sub

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I am working on exporting a combination of shapes to a certain dimension and I am running into the a problem with freeform shapes running off the edge of the slide which messes up my dimensions for the export image.

I know you can crop pictures just fine but I haven't been able to find anything on cropping freeform shapes.

UPDT: Is it possible to use a blank rectangle to capture the part of the freeform that is on the slide but then keep the transparency property of the rectangle? Because I need the rectangle to be transparent with the free form drawing floating in it.

NEW Question: I have a user form that has command buttons to run macros, but I want the macro's to be hidden from the menu as private subs but the code doesn't work when they are private.

```
Private sub command button click1()
  Vbaproject.macroname
End Sub

Private Sub macroname()
Run some code
More code
End with
End sub
```

It works with a normal sub but it can't seem to find the private sub.

Comment: Can You put a picture for better understanding?

Comment: It says I can't add pictures unless I have 10 reputation. But basically the drawing of the freeform goes past the edge of the slide, where you wouldn't see it if you presented the PowerPoint. But I need to cut off the excess freeform in order for me to the the right output dimensions on a picture.

Comment: Cropping is something that applies particularly (only) to pictures. I don't think you can crop forms; you can resize them (but that would change the flow/shape of the freeform). So, ensure there are no freeforms runing off the sldie.

Comment: If you export shapes as images, can't you crop the images?

Comment: The nature of the thing that is drawn is for the freeform to go off the sides sometimes, so I am looking for a way to keep the shapes the same size when I scale them down to save them. Cropping them afterwards doesn't gaurentee the proper ratios I need. I am not looking to see if I can code vba to take only the freeform image that is inside the rectangle, while keeping the transparency of the rectangle.

Comment: Try creating a new presentation with one slide, sizing the slide as needed for your purposes, then copy/pasting the shapes you want to export to the slide.  Then export the slide as an image.  Only the part of the shapes that appears on the slide will appear in the image.

Comment: That would still leave me with the background not being transparent. I have decided to go forward with just drawing them to the slide dimensions, which I am writing macros for. Many people use the PowerPoint so I have to make it as user friendly as possible. Thank you though!